# Silk Option Missing from Cloth in Psychics Tab

Tags: cloth-simulation

I am trying to make a bed in Blender as part of a personal project but the Silk option is missing under the cloth in the Psychics tab. I have made the surface below have a collision put on it, but I just can't find it! Any help?[image]

Answer (score 1):

Cloth presets are just a script placed within the folder where blender is installed

/blender/*blender version*/scripts/presets/cloth/

create a new text document with the following:

```
import bpy

bpy.context.cloth.settings.quality = 5

bpy.context.cloth.settings.mass = 0.150

bpy.context.cloth.settings.structural_stiffness = 5

bpy.context.cloth.settings.bending_stiffness = 0.05

bpy.context.cloth.settings.spring_damping = 0

bpy.context.cloth.settings.air_damping = 1
```

and save the file as silk.py

Or just use those values on blender and save a new preset using the plus (+) sign on the presets.